# Opening comment box in the same page

Tags: ajax

I want to open a text area when i press the comment button without page getting reloaded.Please help.I am a newbie in this field.
I have tried seeing some tutorials but not of much help.I have never used Jquery before

Comment: 'open a text area' what it mean? hide/show..?

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery code:

hide the textArea element by default.

```
$("#[buttonID]").click(function(){
$("#[textAreaID]").show();
}
```